# How to push values to input type hidden when clicked on radio button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting values from one variable in array format so by using for loop it will iterate and when click on input type radio button each value with comma separated push to hidden field

I tried this but nothing gets inserted. How can I push those values to the hidden field?

```js
var id = ["1", "2"]; // getting this value from another varaible in array format

for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  $("input[name=radion_btn" + id[i] + "]").change(function() {
    $(".selected_val").push(id[i]); //values like 1,2 want to push in hidden field when click on radio button
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="selected_val[]" value="" class="selected_val" />
<input type="radio" name="radion_btn1" value="" />
<input type="radio" name="radion_btn2" value="" />
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `push` does.  It's not for appending/inserting values to an input (hidden or otherwise), it's for adding entries to an array.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Also the looping through a explicit list of numbers to build the `id` strings is far less than ideal. Use a common class on the elements and use a single call the `change` to place the event handler on them all at once

Comment: You could create an array, push whatever to that, and then add the array contents to the input using `$(".selected_val").val(JSON.stringify(arr))`.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I want to push values comma separated, one by one when click on radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code. `for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {` run two times and whenever your event occur. At that time  i value come 2 and id[2] comes undefined. Below code should work.

```js
var id = ["1", "2"]; // getting this value from another varaible in array format
arrayData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  $("input[name=radion_btn" + id[i] + "]").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    arrayData.push($(this).val()); //values like 1,2 want to push in hidden field when click on radio button
    $('.selected_val').val(arrayData.join());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="value" name="selected_val[]" value="" class="selected_val" />
<input type="radio" name="radion_btn1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radion_btn2" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a push by adding the hidden input's value before the new value

```
var id = ["1", "2"]; // getting this value from another varaible in array format

for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  $(".selected_val").val("");
  $("input[name=radion_btn" + id[i] + "]").change(function() {
    $(".selected_val").val((i == 0 ? "" : ",") + $(".selected_val").val() + id[i]);
  });
}
```

Comment: jQuery objects do not have a `push()` method

Comment: I started to make this a snippet to show it working but realised it wouldn't because you use `i` inside the closure `(i==0?""` and `i` will never be `0` at that point, and `id[i]` will be `id[2]` which will be blank or error.  Using `.val()` (or `.text()`) is the correct answer, but will not work in this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one approach that might help. See comments in snippet below.

```js
let obj = {};  // create an empty object to store the clicked values
$(".radio").change(function() {  // when a radio button is clicked
  obj[this.id] = $(this).val();  // store it in the object
  $(".selected_val").val(JSON.stringify(obj));  // and add the object to hidden field as string
  console.log($(".selected_val").val());  // spit it out to the console
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="selected_val[]" value="" class="selected_val" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="radion_btn1" id="1" value="1" />1
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="radion_btn2" id="2" value="2" />2
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="radion_btn3" id="3" value="3" />3
```

You'll notice I added a common class for all radio buttons. This is what I'm attaching the event handler to. I also added the IDs to the radio button elements as well.

This may or may not work best for your scenario, but hopefully gets you started in the right direction.

**Update**

If you'd rather store the values in an array, just change it to an array:

```
let arr = [];
$(".radio").change(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
    $(".selected_val").val(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

Of course, that won't associate the ID with the value like with an object.

Comment: but i want to get those values in php so it will be better if it store in array format instead of object

Comment: You can certainly decode a JSON string in PHP using `json_decode`, see [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). But if you don't want to store it in an object, then just change the object to an array and store the array values instead.